# Pressing key on keyboard and clicking mouse

Tags: windows-7, keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, mouse

When I press any key on my keyboard and click my mouse it causes a delay and then mouse will act as if I haven't stopped clicking even though I have.

Also when I press any key for too long, tab for example, it will lock and will continue that key command for 5 seconds after I have let go of the key.

Also sometimes when this happens the entire screen will lag and make a beeping noise.

I have tried system restores and they have not worked.

```
OS:Windows 7 Ultimate Edition 
Processor: i5 4690k @3.5GHZ
Memory: Hyper X Fury 16GB
Hard Drive: Seagate 1TB 72000rpm
Motherboard: Gigabyte H81M-H
```

I Don't think the specs matter to much but just in case

Comment: Mention your keyboard and mouse connection type (USB / PS/2).

Comment: they connection type is USB

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you have enabled Sticky Keys, a disability option that is part of Windows.

Go to your control panel, Ease of Access Center.

Scroll down and find "Make the Mouse easier to use"

Uncheck "Turn on Mouse Keys"

You may want to uncheck the rest too if they're on.

Press <kbd>OK</kbd> and again scroll down. Now click Make the keyboard easier to use.

Uncheck everything here too.

Press <kbd>OK</kbd> here too, and it should all be back to normal.